# --fake-initial vs --fake in Django migration?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-migrations

What is the difference between `--fake-initial` and `--fake` in Django  migrations? What are the dangers of using fake migrations? Anybody knows? Thank you very much to all.

I am using django 1.10

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Well [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake) is very clear about this

### --fake-initial

> Allows Django to skip an app’s initial migration if all database
> tables with the names of all models created by all CreateModel
> operations in that migration already exist. This option is intended
> for use when first running migrations against a database that
> preexisted the use of migrations. This option does not, however, check
> for matching database schema beyond matching table names

You were asking about the risks, well here it is

> only safe to use if you are confident that your existing schema
> matches what is recorded in your initial migration.

### --fake

> Tells Django to mark the migrations as having been applied or
> unapplied, but without actually running the SQL to change your
> database schema.
>
> This is intended for advanced users to manipulate the current
> migration state directly if they’re manually applying changes;

Once again risks are clearly highlighted

> be warned that using --fake runs the risk of putting the migration
> state table into a state where manual recovery will be needed to make
> migrations run correctly.

This answer is valid not just for django versions 1.8+ but for other versions as well.

edit Nov, 2018: I sometimes I see answers here and elsewhere that suggest that you should drop your databae. That's almost never the right thing to do. If you drop your database you lose all your data.

Comment: A similar advanced question about [migrate --fake and  --fake-initial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772762/django-migrate-fake-and-fake-initial-explained/46774336#46774336) quoted all these documentation paragraphs and still asked why it is useful. There is answered how and when these options can be used safely enough in practice.

Answer (score 10):

Short answer

- `--fake` **does not** apply the migration
- `--fake-initial` **might, or might not** apply the migration

Longer answer:

`--fake`: Django keeps a table called `django_migrations` to know which migrations it has applied in  the past, to prevent you from accidentally applying them again. All `--fake` does is insert the migration filename into that table, **without actually running** the migration. This is useful if you manually changed the database schema first, and the models later, and want to bypass django's actions. However, during that step you are on your own, so take care that you don't end up in an inconsistent state.

`--fake-initial`: depends on the state of the database

- **all of the tables** already exist in the database: in that case, it works like `--fake`. **Only the names** of the tables are checked, not their actual schema, so, again, take care
- **none of the tables** already exist in the database: in that case, it works like a normal migration
- **some of the table** already exist: you get an error. That's not supposed to happen, either you take care of the database, or django does.

Note that, `--fake-initial` is only taken into account if the migration file has `initial=True` in its class, otherwise the flag is ignored. Also, this is the only documented usage of `initial=True` in migrations.

Comment: This is the answer for those who have read the docs but didn't understand it. Not just pointing to documentation, but explaining, with own words, or maybe from other point of view. Good job and thank you.

Answer (score 9):

@e4c5 already gave an answer about this question, but I would like to add one more thing concerning when to use `--fake` and `--fake-initial`.

Suppose you have a database from production and you want to use it for development and apply migrations without destroying the data.  In that case `--fake-initial` comes in handy.

The `--fake-initial` will force Django to look at your migration files and basically skip the creation of tables that are already in your database. Do note, though, that any migrations that don’t create tables (but rather modify existing tables) will be run.

Conversely, If you have an existing project with migration files and you want to reset the history of existing migrations, then `--fake` is usually used.

Comment: @heikki thanks for your edit suggestion and my answer looks way more perfect right now.

Comment: The last statement in this post is important if you are looking to reset migrations without losing data in an existing Django project. For some reason I was getting `table already exists` errors using `--fake-initial` as described here: https://dev.to/k4ml/django-migrate---fake-initial-gotchas-2fih the solution was to truncate the `django_migrations` table, delete all migration files, then run initial migrations and `--fake` them since the DB is already up to date so the intial migration files are added to the DB correctly without actually being run