# Added another column to a model in Django, how do I update database?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

So I changed the names and added a column to a model in django.

Before:

```
class MyApp(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    aaa = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bbb = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

After:

```
class MyApp(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    second = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    third = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I made these changes in the MyApp's view, model, and serializer, however when I try to access my new API endpoint, it fails because the database doesn't contain the new column names.  How can I update the database to reflect my new model? (I don't care about any of the data for this model, so I can wipe it).  No idea how to do this

Comment: stupid question but did you make migrations and migrated afterwards?

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov I made migrations, the migrations for the app I chose were successfully generated (I also checked, it generated the folder), but when I went to migrate it said no changes were detected so I thought it must be something else.

Comment: sound like migrations where not applied. try to run migrations and specify the name of the app -> python manage.py migrate your_app_name

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov still get no migrations applied

Comment: did you make migrations for this app before?

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov Yes, I have migrated, the current schema (the before in my code) has data in it and functioning.  However, I need my app to have a new schema, but I don't care if I lose the data.   I think I got further with the error though.  It now reconizes there is something to migrate however I get `django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "MyApps_MyApp" already exists`

Comment: can you post your migrations because there is not enough info about what is happening. Look like your migrations tries to create new table, but should update the old one.

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov I ended up just having to go into the database and drop the table.  That fixed it

Comment: great! If you don't care about data and tables then probably it is the easiest way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run the commands

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname

python manage.py migrate appname
```

If you get *table already exists* run command

```
python manage.py migrate --fake appname
```

This solved the problem when I had it.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#initial-migrations

Comment: Wouldn't `--fake-initial` be more appropriate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42695629/fake-initial-vs-fake-in-django-migration