# django.db.utils.InternalError: (1050, "Table 'django_content_type' already exists")

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

django.db.utils.InternalError: (1050, "Table 'django_content_type' already exists")

I just copied a project from my friend, when I run makemirations it runs properly. But for -

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

it gives this error -

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, balancesheet, contenttypes, dynapp, pandl2, sessions, trialbal2
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1050, "Table 'django_content_type' already exists")
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 92, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 307, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 137, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
django.db.utils.InternalError: (1050, "Table 'django_content_type' already exists")


 django.db.utils.InternalError: (1050, "Table 'django_content_type' already exists")
```

When I opened MySQL to delete 'DJANGO_CONTENT_TYPE table with drop table command, it gives this error -

```
mysql> drop table django_content_type;
ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Ie I cant delete this table.

I did migrations because I did some changes in model.

Though I found an alternative to bypass this error not by logic. I created a nee database and changed settings to new database. Here I copied the content from initial database to another.

Comment: I think a well written answer is already mentioned here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23293136/9279181

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta try `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0` then drop table

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi where should I set SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0?

Comment: @GauravGupta in mysql shell, then drop table

Comment: Have you tried to tuncate the table? `delete from django_content_type`

Comment: Don’t drop the content type table - it will corrupt any data that is currently pointing to it. If you copy the database from somewhere else’s, then you must copy the migration files and migrations database table to keep everything in sync.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For django3:
I get this error:
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'name' in 'django_content_type'")

1. Delete myapp/migrations/0001_initial.py and 0002_ .....
2. Delete all rows from the django_migrations table.

   ```
   Delete * from django_migrations
   ```
3. `python3 manage.py makemigrations`

or

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

4. `python3 manage.py migrate --fake-initial`

or

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

5. I get this error:
   MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'name' in 'django_content_type'")
6. I add a column to django_content_type table.

   alter table django_content_type add name varchar(255)
7. `python3 manage.py migrate --fake-initial`
8. This error appears django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1061, "Duplicate key name 'django_site_domain_a2e37b91_uniq'")
9. I did not do anything about this error but my website works perfectly.
   'name' column will remove

Comment: This workaround went nice with Django 3.2

Answer (score 0):

My problem got solved by first deleting database , migration and **pycache** from my apps and finally deleting my virtualenv and creating a new one.

Comment: Recreating virtualenv does not make any sense if it related to migrations.